# How to find an image within another image using python

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to use python to determine if one (small) image is within another (large) image.

Any suggestions before I take myself completely down the wrong path?

/edit: Ok, some ideas:  I'm using PIL, and I'm converting each image to the 'P' mode so I can compare each pixel as an integer.  I'm trying to implement something like a Boyer–Moore string search or the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm, but in 2 dimensions.

Maybe this will help: instead of searching for `ABC in XXXABCXXX` (answer=4) we are searching for

```
ABC    
DEF    
GHI
```

in

```
XXXXX        
XABCX        
XDEFX       
XGHIX    
XXXXX
```

(answer=(2,2))

Comment: Are you looking for the small image exactly or could the image be rotated/skewed/scaled/etc.?

Comment: Zach, have you ever solved this? I'm in the same boat right now

Comment: @mikew I never solved this beyond the naive algorithm I posted below.  I suspect you can solve this problem with OpenCV, but I never found any example code.  I'd also still be interested to see a good solution in pure python.

Comment: Since this is the top search result at the moment on google, future viewers may be interested in a [(much) faster approach using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853628/how-do-i-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT:  Ok, here is the naive way to do this:

```
import Image, numpy

def subimg(img1,img2):
    img1=numpy.asarray(img1)
    img2=numpy.asarray(img2)

    #img1=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
    #img2=numpy.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,3,0],[0,4,5,6,0],[0,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])

    img1y=img1.shape[0]
    img1x=img1.shape[1]

    img2y=img2.shape[0]
    img2x=img2.shape[1]

    stopy=img2y-img1y+1
    stopx=img2x-img1x+1

    for x1 in range(0,stopx):
        for y1 in range(0,stopy):
            x2=x1+img1x
            y2=y1+img1y

            pic=img2[y1:y2,x1:x2]
            test=pic==img1

            if test.all():
                return x1, y1

    return False

small=Image.open('small.tif')
big=Image.open('big.tif')

print subimg(small, big)
```

It works just fine, but I want to SPEED IT UP.  I think the key is in the array 'test' which we might be able to use to skip some positions in the image.

Edit 2: Make sure you use images in a loss-less format to test this.

On `Mac`, install Pillow and `from PIL import Image`

Answer (score 8):

[Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu) does it using OpenCV, see [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vgod/sikuli/trunk/annotate/head:/sikuli-script/src/main/native/template-matcher.cc#L254) how `match_by_template` works and then use the Python OpenCV bindings to do the same. Doing it without OpenCV should be hard, take a look at OpenCV documentation, search for template matching, etc...

Answer (score 4):

`pyautogui` module does the job using `pyautogui.locate(small_image, large_image)` method which returns 4-integer tuple: `(left, top, width, height)`.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little late, but you can use Boyer-Moore to search for the first line of the small image in each of the lines of the large image. The moment you find a match you have the X and Y position and you just have to check if the remainder of the lines of the smaller image match the remainder of the lines of the larger image starting at position X and Y+1,2,3,... At the first mismatch continue with the search of the first line. I don't think you can get faster than this.

Comment: i too would really appreciate an example of how to use Boyer-Moore(-Horspool) in 2d space

Comment: actually this answer only does optimising in one dimension, on the X plane. you are speeding up the search of the horizontal search using B-M by shifting across. but then you are doing naive search in the veritcal plane, since you are never shifting down. still, its very intuitive and definitely an improvement

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to a similar question for a [code example using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253805/1132850). The conversion from PIL to numpy is straight forward, e.g. just use `np.array(pilimage)`.