# OpenCV Template Matching is matching everything with one-color reference image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an reference image I want to match on screenshot. It is part of screenshot, so it's must definitely match.

Image to find: >[image: needleImage]<

Full screenshot:

[image: haystackImage]

So, with OpenCV pyscreeze matches images like these:

```
# get all matches at once, credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670112/finding-a-subimage-inside-a-numpy-image/9253805#9253805
result = cv2.matchTemplate(haystackImage, needleImage, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
match_indices = numpy.arange(result.size)[(result > confidence).flatten()]
matches = numpy.unravel_index(match_indices[:limit], result.shape)
```

some tests:

```
opencv + numpy confidence 1.0: 0 matches
first ten: []
Bench passed in 0.205 seconds

opencv + numpy confidence default (0.999): 1795428 matches
first ten: [(0, 0, 13, 13), (1, 0, 13, 13), (2, 0, 13, 13), (3, 0, 13, 13), (4, 0, 13, 13), (5, 0, 13, 13), (6, 0, 13, 13), (7, 0, 13, 13), (8, 0, 13, 13), (9, 0, 13, 13)]
Bench passed in 0.852 seconds

pure python method: 6690 matches
first ten: [(1855, 208, 13, 13), (1856, 208, 13, 13), (1857, 208, 13, 13), (1858, 208, 13, 13), (1859, 208, 13, 13), (1860, 208, 13, 13), (1861, 208, 13, 13), (1862, 208, 13, 13), (1863, 208, 13, 13), (1864, 208, 13, 13)]

Bench passed in 1.344 seconds
```

I've played with confidence, matching methods, but with OpenCV results are same. It's matched every single pixel or not matching everything.

Pure python method from pyscreeze give most proper results - it's matching images properly.

Maybe I don't need something like OpenCV to match part of screenshot? But pure python is 5-10 times slower.

Comment: Using `TM_SQDIFF` and picking the indices where `result == 0.0` seems to work fine for me. ([Here](https://i.imgur.com/FKqMmEh.png)'s the input image with matches highlighted in yellow.)

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! It helps :)

Comment: Why not just threshold the image since you're looking for a pure color anyways?