# How do I find an image contained within an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I'm currently building what basically amounts to a cross between a search engine and a gallery for web comics that's focused on citing sources and giving authors credit.

I'm trying to figure out a way to search an image to find characters within it.

For example:

[image: cyanide and happiness]

Assuming I have the red character and the green character saved as Red Man and Green Man how do I determine if an image contains one or the other.

This doesn't need to have 100% recognition or anything is this is more of an added feature I'd like to create, I'm just not sure where to start. I've done a lot of googling for image recognition but haven't found much helpful.

For what it's worth, I'd prefer to do this using Python.

Comment: I don't see how sikuli would be used for this. Sikuli looks like it's strictly for GUI interfaces. These are user uploaded pictures on a web server.

Comment: Sikuli is not only for GUI's. You can technically use it to run any Jython script you want.  You could write a script that would open the user images then look for the image pattern you want to find.  That's just a first blush idea.

Comment: However, Sikuli doesn't support scaling or rotation in images....

Answer (score 82, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this in the future.

This can be done with [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cv2.matchTemplate). To summarize (my understanding), template matching looks for an exact match of one image within another image.

Here's an example of how to do it within Python:

```
import cv2

method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED

# Read the images from the file
small_image = cv2.imread('small_image.png')
large_image = cv2.imread('large_image.jpeg')

result = cv2.matchTemplate(small_image, large_image, method)

# We want the minimum squared difference
mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

# Draw the rectangle:
# Extract the coordinates of our best match
MPx,MPy = mnLoc

# Step 2: Get the size of the template. This is the same size as the match.
trows,tcols = small_image.shape[:2]

# Step 3: Draw the rectangle on large_image
cv2.rectangle(large_image, (MPx,MPy),(MPx+tcols,MPy+trows),(0,0,255),2)

# Display the original image with the rectangle around the match.
cv2.imshow('output',large_image)

# The image is only displayed if we call this
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I agree with Moshe but I believe it should be `cv2.matchtemplate(large_image, small_image, method)`. Also here is another good source of information for [template matching](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching) in python.

Comment: Weirdly enough `from cv2 import cv` raises `ImportError: cannot import name 'cv'` while `import cv2` works just fine…

Comment: SOLUTION: Ok so as I'm using Py3, it actually uses OpenCV3 despite it still imports as `cv2` so some stuff have changed places/names.

Comment: Will it work if one of the image is present as low opacity in other image.(On of the input images is watermarked in other image.)

Comment: I had to `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv` for this to work on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 92):

As [Moshe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15147009/1524913) only covers matching a template that is contained only once in the given picture. Here's how matching several at once:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('mario.png')
template = cv2.imread('mario_coin.png')
w, h = template.shape[:-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = .8
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):  # Switch columns and rows
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', img_rgb)
```

(Note: I changed and fixed a few *'mistakes'* that were in the original code)

**Result:**

[image: detect mario coins (before/after)]

**Source:** https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching-with-multiple-objects

Comment: FWIW, I used your code here to test something else and it appears to me that the line `w, h = template.shape[:-1]` should be `h, w = template.shape[:-1]`, at least with my test images (it is consistent across 3 sets of images)

Comment: Just grab the source code from the source link in his answer; it is up to date and works.

Comment: This is the best

Answer (score 2):

Important note: matchTemplate is even able to detect resized and rotated templates. Here's the code and outputs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('/content/picture.png')
template = cv2.imread('/content/penguin.png')
heat_map = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

h, w, _ = template.shape
y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(heat_map), heat_map.shape)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 5)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Image:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc0X5.png)
Template:
[penguin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pzSF.png)
Result:
[detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcNXm.png)

Detailed explanaition over here (my blog): [simple-ai.net/find-and-replace-in-image](https://www.simple-ai.net/post/find-and-replace-in-image)

Comment: Blog link is down

Comment: For this simplified example it may work with resize and rotation, but not in even a little more complex scenarios. Claiming this is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has a Python interface that you could look at. If the characters, don't change too much you could try to use the [matchTemplate](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cv.MatchTemplate) function.

[Here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#template-matching) is their official tutorial on it (the tutorial is written using the C++ interface, but you should be able to get a good idea of how to use the function in Python from it).

Comment: None of the links work. -.-