# How to make a perfect match between to image?

Tags: python, opencv

Here is the link I find 
[How do I find an image contained within an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853628/how-do-i-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image)

And I get the code in the link above.

Here is my code

```
import re
import os
import time
import cv2
from cv2 import cv

METHOD = cv.CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED

ROOTDIR = 'GeneralIMG/'

# Load The Deck Img
LARGE_IMAGE = cv2.imread('deck.bmp')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOTDIR):
    for myfile in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, myfile)

# Read the images from the file
        # small_image = cv2.imread(myfile)
        # small_image = cv2.imread('GeneralIMG/cfrB.bmp')
        Ffile = subdir + myfile 
        small_image = cv2.imread(Ffile)

        result = cv2.matchTemplate(small_image, LARGE_IMAGE, METHOD)

# We want the minimum squared difference
        mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        MPx,MPy = mnLoc
        if MPx == 0 and MPy == 0:
            print 'Match failure!'
        else:
            print MPx, MPy
            print re.sub(r"B|D", "", os.path.splitext(myfile)[0])

# Draw the rectangle:
# Extract the coordinates of our best match
        MPx,MPy = mnLoc

# Step 2: Get the size of the template. This is the same size as the match.
        trows,tcols = small_image.shape[:2]

# Step 3: Draw the rectangle on LARGE_IMAGE
        cv2.rectangle(LARGE_IMAGE, (MPx,MPy),(MPx+tcols,MPy+trows),(0,0,255),2)

# Display the original image with the rectangle around the match.
        cv2.imshow('output',LARGE_IMAGE)

# The image is only displayed if we call this
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        # time.sleep(5)
```

This is the **small pic** which I want to find in the large image but the large image don't contain the small image. To my surprise the matchTemplate still get the result.

[12~07_00-03-03.bmp http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/12~07_00-03-03.bmp](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/12~07_00-03-03.bmp)

But the match result I get is not accurate enough like the pic below. The **red rectangle** is the match result.

[12~07_00-01-58.bmp http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/12~07_00-01-58.bmp](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/12~07_00-01-58.bmp)

Here I want to find exact the same pic in the large one. If not contain it, just return a false will be fine. I don't want a fuzzy search what should I do?

--- update ---

this is the small img:

[small img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q723F.png)

This is the original larger bmp image

[large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4kf7.png)

When the image is uploaded the format will be changed. The small img is png file, and the larger is bmp.

Thing is I wonder if the matchtemplate use the fuzzy search here. So the issue here why I get the wrong search result seems reasonable. I want to know how to make the search exactly. Thx~

update:

I check the doc of the [matchtemplate]

And I find this which means it is a best match search not perfect match.

So How can I make it perfect match ?

**What is template matching?
Template matching is a technique for finding areas of an image that match (are similar) to a template image (patch).**

Comment: I don't believe that exact sub image is in your final image - I believe you may have saved the file as a JPEG or done something else to it before posting it - in fact you must have edited it to draw the red box. Remember JPEG files are not exact - they are lossy so just opening and re-saving a JPEG will likely change the contents to no longer be a perfect copy of the original. Have you got the **original** of the larger image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the result shows that the the subimg is found and the exact coordinates of it in the larger image is given. I wonder the matchtemplate use fuzzy search instead of precise search here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried applying a threshold on the results given by `minMaxLoc`?

I never used `matchTemplate` and `minMaxLoc` so I don't really know how it works, but from what I understand, if what you want is a perfect match, then the value you are looking for could possibly be 0 (or 1, depending on your METHOD parameter). So if you discard every other value, you shouldn't get positive results unless you have a perfect match.

Comment: I read the doc of the matchtemplate the search is a fuzzy search. Matchtmeplate will find the highest match instead of perfect match

Comment: @Lee what is the value of your best match then? Perhaps you could try a threshold not on perfect match (so 0 or 1), but on some value in-between. Plus I'm not even sure you could be able to find a perfect match with other method anyway, because it seems it depends on the ratio between the scale of your small image and its integration in the big image I guess...

Comment: Ok I can't edit my comment so I'm gonna add it here: since `matchTemplate` combined to `minMaxLoc` pretty much always output a result no matter how awful it is, if you don't use thresholds you might consider opting for another solution like feature tracking or meanshift using histograms back projection, which could be more robust but won't give you perfect matches either and seems kind of "overkill" to me for what you want to do. I fear that exact matching template might be computationally expensive

Comment: You mean that if I use the `thresholds` I can implement the perfect match? I go through the doc again~ Thing is that I don't have to use the **perfect match** but the result I get now is wrong which is unacceptable. You can check the image in the post different img means different character if I get the wrong character I may lose the game.

Comment: I said that because I thought `matchTemplate` could give accurate results. I am not saying that you can implement the perfect match with thresholds if `matchTemplate` and `minMaxLoc` provide the best match (so not exact match, but only the closest one). However, what I suggested is that you look at the best match value given by your algorithm in this case. If you have, let's say 70% match accuracy, then you could say that this is not enough to be considered a match. So maybe you could expect a 99% match accuracy instead to consider your match perfect since 100% doesn't seem reachable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get perfect matching using cv.matchTemplate:
use method cv.TM_SQDIFF and threshold the absolute values of the result at <= 1/16

Mathematically all patches with perfect matching should have a squared diff of 0, not [-0.0625,0.0625]. However, the optimization in the actual implementation of cv.matchTemplate result in slight differences (at least the function ippiSqrDistanceNorm used at OpenCV 4.5.1 did for uint8 input and 3x3 uint8 masks)

Note that the matching compares starting from the left/top corner, not the center of the template, so if you want to get all pixels with the exact surrounding as your template, you have to add an offset of half the template's width and height.