# How to recognition a small image from the big one with java using opencv

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

**My Goal:**
I Want to recognize a portion of a big image from the big image using `OpenCV` lib in java.

**Input:**
Eg. I have 2 images, One is a forest and another one is a cropped image of the first one.

**Expected Output:**
now I want the output image should mark the area where the cropped image fits perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find an image contained within an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853628/how-do-i-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into matchtemplate [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)