# locating a picture inside a bigger picture

Tags: python, matlab, computer-vision, slam

I'm in the middle of a school project on computer vision that consists on two parts. The first part is the semantic segmentation of a ground picture (small picture) and the second part consists in being able to locate that small picture in a pre-loaded and pre-segmented map (big picture) with the output being the coordinates and the orientation of the small picture inside the big one.

The first part is already done and working fine, but I have no idea how to approach the second part of the project. When the small picture's orientation is the same as in the original map, I can easily find it using brute force, but problems start when the small image is rotated respect to the original map.

I have no idea how to approach this problem, any word, topic or algorithms I could use to look for more information online would be appreciated :)

I'm working on **Matlab** with the Deep learning and computer vision toolboxes, but I could easily change to **Python** if needed or if it could be substantially easier.

Thanks to everyone reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the word "brute force", I don't understand what you mean. If you provide more detail may be I be able to provide more details or more alogrithms. However if you want to find search image in side same or another image you can use these algorithms: 
- `SIFT` 
- `SURF` 
- `ORB` 
- `BRISK` 
- `FREAK` 
- **Siamese networks**

Most of these algorithms (expect last one) try to `find some key points` that are robust against rotations, noise, brightness variations, blur, ... and `finally match them` using distance measurement such as hamming, euclidean, manhatan, ....

*I my self the prefer last one in terms of accuracy and not needing playing with too many hyper-parameters*. For `Siamese networks` you need `training`. It means labeling and GPU. `SIFT` and `SURF` are famous for image matching. For more details you can read their main articles. I wrote a paper on `copy-move forgery` that finds copy-pasting an part of image for fraud/forgery purpose. You can find a lot of approaches for your purpose from papers of this field.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks! I read the documentation on those algorithms and ended up using SURF as you suggested, easy to implement on Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this, I typically use the machine learning library of OpenCV, which contains thousands of algorithms in relation to computer vision. If you are having issues with rotation of images, look into this [tutorial here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d66/tutorial_feature_detection.html), which takes an input image and rotates, warps, etc, to desired dimensions that could be used later. In this stack post, the user is able to find an image within a larger image

[How do I find an image contained within an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853628/how-do-i-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image)

Comment: Very useful resources, thanks Aaron! I ended up using the other solution because I found it easier to implement in Matlab, which was my preferred platform :D