# Find image inside image using nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, opencv

Using nodejs, how can I get the coordinates of an image that is inside a larger image ?

From my research, this probably can be done using opencv library, but I didn't find a complete answer.
All I've found is [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35378944) to that same problem, but using Python