# Trouble finding multiple instances of template with different scales using cv2 in Python

Tags: python, templates, matching, opencv

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1VX0.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZGaO.png)

I'm trying to code a python script that uses the cv2 library to template match an image. I have figured out how to detect one instance of the template in the image, taking into account if the template has a different scale, but i can't seem to figure out how to find multiple instances of a template in an image taking into account the scale as well.

I tried finding the first match, blocking it, then running the scan again, but the second scan can't find the template correctly.[image with bounding boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWqD1.png)
[image to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fb3a.png)

Does anyone know what can I do for it to detect both instances?

Here is the code im running:

```
import numpy as np
import imutils
import glob
import cv2
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression


imagen_a_detectar = r"C:\Users\OMEN\OneDrive\Documentos\TEC\PROYECTO RESIDEO\REPO\SCRUMsinCUM\software\Deteccion Iconos\flecha50.jpg"
imagen_a_comparar = r"C:\Users\OMEN\OneDrive\Documentos\TEC\PROYECTO RESIDEO\REPO\SCRUMsinCUM\software\Deteccion Iconos\HomeAuto3.png"

template = cv2.imread(imagen_a_detectar)
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]

for imagePath in glob.glob(imagen_a_comparar):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None
    threshold = 0.9

    for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
        scalem = scale
        resized = imutils.resize(gray, width = int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
        r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

        if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
            break
        edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)

        result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        if found is None or max_val > found[0]:
            found = (max_val, max_loc, r)


    (_, max_loc, r) = found
    (startX, startY) = (int(max_loc[0] * r), int(max_loc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((max_loc[0] + tW) * r), int((max_loc[1] + tH) * r))
    m1 = cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), -1)

    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(m1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    resized2 = imutils.resize(gray2, width = int(gray.shape[1] * scalem))
    r2 = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])
    edged2 = cv2.Canny(resized2, 50, 200)

    result2 = cv2.matchTemplate(edged2, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val2, max_val2, min_loc2, max_loc2 = cv2.minMaxLoc(result2)
    found2 = (max_val2, max_loc2, r2)
    
    (_, max_loc2, r2) = found2
    (startX2, startY2) = (int(max_loc2[0] * r2), int(max_loc2[1] * r2))
    (endX2, endY2) = (int((max_loc2[0] + tW) * r2), int((max_loc2[1] + tH) * r2))

    m2 = cv2.rectangle(m1, (startX2, startY2), (endX2, endY2), (0, 0, 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("Image", m2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    print(str(endX) + ' ' +str(endY)+ ' ' +str(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35378944/12363750), slightly modified:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('image.png')
tmp_rgb = cv2.imread('template.png')

for template in [tmp_rgb, np.flip(tmp_rgb, axis=1)]:
    w, h = template.shape[:-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = .8
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

plt.imshow(img_rgb)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I already had that working. The problem I am facing is that one of detecting multiple instances of the template when the scale of the template is different from the scale of the image.