# Looking for a Python function to detect multiple images in one image

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python function that will allow me to check whether an image is composed of multiple images or not. I have checked this website, http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm, but I haven't been able to find a function that would allow me to do so. It will be greatly appreciated if somebody can help me here..

Comment: You'll need much more than a function to do that. Check out this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3049370/249552).

Comment: @jacob, thank you very much! I'll check that one!