# Detect location of specific text

Tags: python, ios, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

```
Appium 1.5.0 
Xcode  7.3 
IOS 10.11.4 OSX EI Capitan
Using on:Simulator iOS 8.1
```

Suppose we have a text field `To see more information click`**here**`and to get more click` **here**.

So I identified the text using `xpath` and I can get its location and size.
Now can we somehow get the location of **here** .I need to click it, but because it is not an element I cannot search for it.  So somehow if I can get its location, I can `tap` at that.

But how can we get its location and still keep it generic so that it runs on different devices?

Comment: You can refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349725/character-index-at-touch-point-for-uilabel

Comment: I have an idea but I don't know Appium, can you use Objective C with it ?

Comment: @AnthoninC. unfortunately have to use appium...still can you share the idea.....as an answer...i will try if it works....m doing it in python

Comment: @DungProton i need it in python....through `appium-python` client....do you have any idea how to achieve the same in python

Comment: if you call `source_window` it will return all the elements and their position

Comment: @juhlila the text is embedded but it's not an identifiable element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any direct way to achieve this(no API available in Appium itself).
However, my solution is generic and will work on all devices(Android and iOS), all programming language implementation.

1. [You have already done] get the location and size of the element.
2. Take a screenshot of the current screen.
3. Crop image from the screenshot using the location and size of the image.[This step can be skipped if there are not ambiguous targets]
4. [You need to do this only one time manually] Crop out the image portion you want to get the location.
5. Search the location of the cropped image, get the location and perform a precise tap/click.

For image search refer here : [How to find an image within another image using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049370/how-to-find-an-image-within-another-image-using-python)

Comment: I marked this though its not totally generic as when devices change,the one time manual work will have to be done again...

Answer (score 1):

The idea using Objective C (I know the OP uses Appium but he told me to answer) is to use library such as [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/) and using it this way :

Create `TTTAttributedLabel` (`UILabel` subclass), and put text content in it, as if it was a UILabel. Set its delegate to self. Then, add a link to a word this way :

```
NSRange rangeWord = [attributedLabel.text rangeOfString:@"here"];
[attributedLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"anActionOnClickHere"] withRange:rangeUser];
```

On clicking words it will call this method in which you can handle the click :

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(__unused TTTAttributedLabel *)label
   didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *urlToString = [url absoluteString];

    if ([urlToString containsString:@"anActionOnClickHere"]) { //perform segue for example
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hereSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

I absolutely don't know about Python, hope you will find a equivalent method.

Comment: Thanx....will dive deep though at the outset it seems this might not be possible in python.....will update u